# Importing Graphviz library to C# Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, graphviz

I have to switch my application from Windows XP to Windows 7 operating system. The old WinXp app uses WinGraphviz library by AT&T that's now obsolete. So I am trying to import the new Graphviz library to my C# project.
Visual Studio 2008 requires all references to be COM object or valid assembly. Unfortunately the Graphiviz package I've downloaded from official website doesn't include such files. DLL only is included.

1. Add reference DLL returns with the aforementioned error.
2. Add project folder does not work.
3. Someone suggest to build my own Interupt file but I have no idea.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one will help: [Graphviz4Net](http://graphviz4net.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm constrained to .NET Framework version 2.0. Graphviz4Net is a fair solution but it requires .NET Framework version 4.0